# pandas create a Boolean column for a df based on one condition on a column of another df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two `df`s, `A` and `B`. `A` is like,

```
date        id
2017-10-31  1
2017-11-01  2
2017-08-01  3
```

`B` is like,

```
type    id 
1       1
2       2
3       3
```

I like to create a new boolean column `has_b` for `A`, set the column value to `True` if its corresponding row (`A` joins `B` on `id`) in `B` does not have `type == 1`, and its time delta is > 90 days comparing to `datetime.utcnow().day`; and `False` otherwise, here is my solution

```
    B = B[B['type'] != 1]

    A['has_b'] = A.merge(B[['id', 'type']], how='left', on='id')['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.utcnow().day - x.day > 90)

    A['has_b'].fillna(value=False, inplace=True)
```

expect to see `A` result in,

```
date        id    has_b    
2017-10-31  1     False
2017-11-01  2     False
2017-08-01  3     True
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, in terms of more concise and efficient code.

Comment: @COLDSPEED in last question, I was asking column value matchings between two `df`s, this one is obviously different, in that it asks for creating a new column based on column value conditions on both `df`s.

Comment: No worries, after reading your question a few times, it became clear. :-)

Comment: Sorry, a couple of bugs in my answer, corrected it and it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First merge `A` and `B` on `id` -

```
i = A.merge(B, on='id')
```

Now, compute `has_b` -

```
x = i.type.ne(1)
y = (pd.to_datetime('today') - i.date).dt.days.gt(90)
i['has_b'] = (x & y)
```

Merge back `i` and `A` -

```
C = A.merge(i[['id', 'has_b']], on='id')
C

        date  id  has_b
0 2017-10-31   1  False
1 2017-11-01   2  False
2 2017-08-01   3   True
```

---

**Details**

`x` will return a boolean mask for the first condition.

```
i.type.ne(1)

0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: type, dtype: bool
```

`y` will return a boolean mask for the second condition. Use `to_datetime('today')` to get the current date, subtract this from the date column, and access the days component with `dt.days`.

```
(pd.to_datetime('today') - i.date).dt.days.gt(90)

0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

---

In case, `A` and `B`'s IDs do not align, you may need a *left* merge instead of an inner merge, for the last step -

```
C = A.merge(i[['id', 'has_b']], on='id', how='left')
```

C's `has_b` column will contain NaNs in this case.